# LEFT JOIN and ORDER BY modified behavior between android 4 and lower versions?

Tags: android, sqlite

i have an app that makes this SQL query to a database with two tables, a table with items and a table with datesets. Each dataset can be from a item, and it is a set of dates ( :) )

> SELECT distinct items.date from items left join datesets on
>   items.inicio=datesets.capoID and items.capoID=datesets.capoID ORDER
>   BY datesets.date

I am ordering by datesets.date because date is a integer representing the date, for example: 1357340400

On android 4.X phones the query gives me correctly ordered result. The result of the query is:

```
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 16-03-2012
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 01-06-2012
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 22-06-2012
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 21-07-2012
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 26-09-2012
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 30-10-2012
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 05-12-2012
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 08-12-2012
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 27-12-2012
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 05-01-2013
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 25-02-2013
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 10-03-2013
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 23-04-2013
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 27-04-2013
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 11-05-2013
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 23-06-2013
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 01-07-2013
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 15-08-2013
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 11-09-2013
11-28 13:24:09.457: I/System.out(9148): 21-09-2013
```

In Android 3.2, 2.3, etc (lower versions than 4), the result is incorrect, is not properly ordered:

```
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 01-06-2012
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 16-03-2012
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 21-07-2012
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 26-09-2012
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 22-06-2012
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 30-10-2012
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 08-12-2012
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 27-12-2012
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 05-01-2013
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 05-12-2012
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 25-02-2013
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 10-03-2013
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 23-04-2013
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 27-04-2013
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 11-05-2013
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 23-06-2013
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 01-07-2013
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 15-08-2013
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 11-09-2013
11-28 13:22:50.734: I/System.out(3181): 21-09-2013
```

EDIT:

i use thid code to print the dates:

```
 cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            System.out.println(cursor.getString(3)); 
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
```

Comment: That's weird because APIs 11-15 (3.0 - 4.0.3) use the same SQLite version.

Comment: so, where is the problem? why it gives erroneus results on lower versions than 4.0?

Comment: can you post the code with cursor and processing of those values?

Comment: no procesing on the values, the code is simply Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(sql, null); (sql is the sql query of the question). And the processing of the cursor is simply to print all the values of items.date from 0 to the end of the cursor in a while bucle

Comment: Can you concatenate the results in a string and then, trace through logCat all at once.

Comment: @AndroidUser99 show me the printing. And paste it in the question, not in the comments

Comment: Tomas, done, check the bottom part of the question

Comment: @AndroidUser99 So you are using `cursor.getString()` even though there is a number? Try to use `getLong`... Also I don't see how your 1357340400 number can be transformed into 21-09-2013.

Comment: @AndroidUser99 Your code seems bad. You can't just call getString if there is a number... It would throw an exception

Comment: Is it correct that `datesets.capoID` appears twice in your query?

Comment: NOOOOOOOOO, items.date is not a date, is a string with such kind of content "01-06-2012", and dataset.date is a number, so my code is fine.

Comment: CL, is correct, capoID is the primary key of items, it is correct to appear two times in the sql sentence, no problem on that

Comment: just to ask...why don't you `order by items.date`? that in no way would explain your connumdrum